# Does Paypal send an IPN message when payment is captured?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We are using Paypal's Authorisation/Capture. When a user manually captures the payment (on the Paypal website), does Paypal send any notification?

We want our backend to recognise payments that have been captured and authorised *versus* payments that haven't been captured yet.

We would also like to be notified about payments that were rejected.

Please note we are not using the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found out that there is no special variable for this, it is simply stored in the 'payment_status' in the IPN message from Paypal.

The statuses relevant to authorisation/capture are:

- Completed (when the payment is captured)
- Refunded (when the payment is refunded)
- Pending (after the user makes payment but before the payment is manually captured)